# Python Selenium random behaviour - findElement sometimes works, sometimes doesnt with seemingly same code

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Using Selenium, Python, Pandas to scrape autotrader.co.uk. I'd like a table of stats of the vehicles listed but for some reason it's proving more difficult than I thought...

Full code here: [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/JDf5gPmQ)

it seems like sometimes the 'title' and the 'price' elements are not recognised, but it's the exact same code on html:

Working item's HTML (row index 1):

```
<section class="product-card-pricing">

     <div class="product-card-pricing__content">

        <div class="product-card-pricing__price">

            <span>£16,500</span>


        </div>


    </div>

</section>
```

Non-working HTML (row index 2):

```
<section class="product-card-pricing">

     <div class="product-card-pricing__content">

        <div class="product-card-pricing__price">

            <span>£12,995</span>


        </div>


    </div>

</section>
```

Element selector:

```
data['Price'] = listing.find_elements_by_css_selector('section.product-card-pricing')[0].text
```

The output looks like this (notice row ID 1 & 2 as per the respective examples)

Any help is massively appreciated!
[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is related to the fact that the site shows a Cookie permission dialog, which adds an html class that prevent the page scroll setting the css overflow to hidden.

That said, selenium tries to scroll to the n-th element below the viewport, but can't, and cannot retrieve anything.

Just add these imports

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

and these lines (first and last lines are the ones on your existing code)

```py
    driver.get('https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?sort=relevance&postcode=se83gt&radius=1500&make=LAND%20ROVER&model=RANGE%20ROVER%20EVOQUE&include-delivery-option=on&seller-type=private&page=' + str(current_page))
    # ADD FROM HERE -----------
    html = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "html.sp-message-open")
        )
    )
    driver.execute_script(
        "arguments[0].setAttribute('class',arguments[1])",
        html, 
        ''
    )
    # TO HERE -----------
    listings = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('li.search-page__result')
```

The above code will produce the following output:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64924/devtools/browser/6d3a45f2-6cbe-47af-8d92-5e52dabb4ad7   
                                               Title    Price  ... Attention Grabber  URL
0  Land Rover Range Rover Evoque 2.2 ED4 Pure Tec...  £10,500  ...               NaN  NaN
1  Land Rover Range Rover Evoque 2.2 TD4 Pure AWD...  £12,995  ...               NaN  NaN
2  Land Rover Range Rover Evoque 2.2 SD4 Pure Tec...  £10,495  ...               NaN  NaN
3  Land Rover Range Rover Evoque 2.2 SD4 Dynamic ...  £16,850  ...               NaN  NaN
4  Land Rover Range Rover Evoque 2.2 SD4 Dynamic ...  £11,999  ...               NaN  NaN
5  Land Rover Range Rover Evoque 2.0 eD4 SE Tech ...  £18,950  ...               NaN  NaN
6  Land Rover Range Rover Evoque 2.2 ED4 Pure 2WD...  £12,000  ...               NaN  NaN
7  Land Rover Range Rover Evoque 2.2 SD4 Pure Tec...  £13,620  ...               NaN  NaN
8  Land Rover Range Rover Evoque 2.0 TD4 HSE Dyna...  £17,900  ...               NaN  NaN
9  Land Rover Range Rover Evoque 2.0 eD4 SE (s/s)...  £18,000  ...               NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks Mattia, worked like a charm! Appreciate the explanation as well. Bounty shall be awarded ASAP - I'm having to wait for another 16 hours but you, sir, have won it!

Comment: Glad to be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Get the subelement of listing css selector wouldn't work here. I'd also add a webdriver wait for the cookies that pop up.

```
data['Price'] = listing.find_element_by_xpath(".//section[@class='product-card-pricing']").text
#print(data['Price'])
data['Title'] = listing.find_element_by_xpath(".//h3[@class='product-card-details__title']").text
#print(data['Title'])
```

Outputs

```
£10,500
Land Rover Range Rover Evoque 2.2 ED4 Pure Tech 2WD 5dr
£16,500
Land Rover Range Rover Evoque 2.2 SD4 Pure Tech AWD 5dr
```

Comment: Thanks @Arundeep, sadly it still doesnt work. See output here: https://imgur.com/a/eyX3jx4